# how to edit pagination behaviour in yii

Tags: yii

hello i am creating a search module which is taking data from apis..
Now i am getting all result in 1 api call and i am making it as a dataProvider.
this is the code..

```
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($result, array(          
                                                    'sort' => array(
                                                    'attributes' => array('name',
                                                            ),
                                                    ),
                                                    'pagination' => array(
                                                            'pageSize' => 10,
                                                    ),
                                            ));
```

this is working fine and giving pagination. What i want to do is to use limit and ofset of api.
for eg consider the yelp api

```
    http://api.yelp.com/search?term="xxx"&location="xxx"&limit=10&ofset=0;
```

i want to get only 10 result initially and i need another api call to get next set when i click the pagination [2] or next >.

how can this be done ?

I also need a expert opinion. which one is better.? calling api at single time and fetch all detail once or getting few one by one ? the expected results will be around 200..

Answer (score 1):

Yelp doesn't allow to "cache" its search results in any meaning http://www.yelp.com/developers/getting_started/api_terms (section 6). So I believe you need to do call each time pagination link is clicked.

For this purpose I would create some YelpDataProvider extended from [`CDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider) and override required abstract methods.

Pagination:

Not sure I got what kind of problem you faced with, but if you implement your own data provider you will have access to [`CPagination`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination) class instance and its properties `pageSize` and `offset`. 
`pageSize` is to be mapped to `limit` yelp request parameter, `offset` property - directly to `offset` request param.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination

```
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($result, array(          
    'sort' => array(
        'attributes' => array('name'),
    ),
    'pagination' => array(
        'pageSize' => 10,
        'offset' => 5
    ),
));
```